# MS Access Database opens in Read-Only mode

Tags: database, ms-access, locking

I have an Access Database (`.accdb`) shared over a network in my company. When I open the database I can only open it in Read-only mode.

Before I opened it, I checked and there was not an `.laccdb` (lock file). When I open the database in Read-only mode the lock file does however gets created.

I know there is not any user currently using the file and I urgently need to do updates.

This is the message I get when I open the file:

[image: Read-Only Access DB]

What steps can I take to open the file in Read-write mode? As I cannot rename the file. Copying to another folder, updating and copying back also does not work.

Comment: How are you sharing it? Also, do you have write permission on the folder it's in?

Comment: Ask the network system administrator to give read-write permission on the folder with accdb file for all users who should work with this file and the error should disappear. Delete permission on accdb file can be revoked

Answer (score 0):

I noticed another user connected to the database with an Excel sheet. The connection was setup in such a way, that when he connects, the database gets locked.

I had to ask the network admin to remove the locks.

This was the users, connection

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=M:\Database.accdb;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False
```